# Create a new angular project logs NPM Warnings: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

When I create a new Angular project I receive these warnings from NPM:

```
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/karma/node_modules/fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

It seems like they are irrelevant as the project serves fine with `ng serve -o`.  Is there a way to switch these off?

This is my `ng --version` result:

```
            Angular CLI: 8.3.0-rc.0
            Node: 12.6.0
            OS: linux x64
            Angular: 8.2.2
            ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
            ... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
            ... router

            Package                           Version
            -----------------------------------------------------------
            @angular-devkit/architect         0.802.2
            @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.802.2
            @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.802.2
            @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.802.2
            @angular-devkit/core              8.2.2
            @angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.0-rc.0
            @angular/cdk                      8.1.3
            @angular/cli                      8.3.0-rc.0
            @angular/material                 8.1.3
            @ngtools/webpack                  8.2.2
            @schematics/angular               8.3.0-rc.0
            @schematics/update                0.803.0-rc.0
            rxjs                              6.4.0
            typescript                        3.5.3
            webpack                           4.38.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding these options to the npm install command:

`--no-optional argument will prevent optional dependencies from being installed.
--no-shrinkwrap argument, which will ignore an available package lock or shrinkwrap file and use the package.json instead.
--no-package-lock argument will prevent npm from creating a package-lock.json file.`